# Unit Test label output

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Can someone help me with this please
How can I check the output of a label on my web page contains a label that starts with a certain string:

This is my code:

```
IWebElement approvedBOm = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("dlBOMLineItems_ctl12_lblApprovalStatus"));
Assert.IsTrue(approvedBOm.ToString().StartsWith("Approved By "));
```

If you look at my code my code one can see that I want to check if the label output starts with "Approved by"

Comment: I suspect that `IWebElement` (what tool are you using here?) probably has further properties to get hold of its contents, whereas `.ToString()` is giving you a representation of the entire object, not just the contents that you want to check.

Comment: what do you mean what tool am using, are your referring to selenium?

Comment: Yes - I meant Selenium, a search for IWebElement indicated that you were probably using it - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium, the `IWebElement` interface has a [`Text` property](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm).  Doing `.ToString()` is giving you a representation of the entire object, rather than returning the actual text of the label.  You should use the `Text` property instead:

```
IWebElement approvedBOm = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("dlBOMLineItems_ctl12_lblApprovalStatus"));
Assert.IsTrue(approvedBOm.Text.StartsWith("Approved By "));
```

One of your comments noted that the label actually contains "Approved by ...".  If that's what you want to test against, you need to change the `StartsWith` check.  If you don't mind what the case is of the text, so long as it's the right text, you could use a case-insensitive check:

```
Assert.IsTrue(approvedBOm.Text.StartsWith("approved by ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Thanks James, but unfortunately the code is still failing, with this -  Assert.IsTrue(approvedBOm.Text.StartsWith("Approved By "));

Comment: Better to edit things into your question rather than putting them in comments - full error messages help etc

Comment: I don't understand your question James

Comment: You say it's failing, _in what way_ is it failing?  Is the `Assert` failing? Are you getting an exception of some sort, perhaps `approvedBOm` is null because the driver hasn't found it?  Rather than replying in the comments here, re-edit your question and document what's happening there instead.

Comment: Because I am doing a Unit test, when I run the Nunit console, the test is failing with that line of code

Comment: But _how_ is it failing... What _specifically_ does it say when it fails?

Comment: Expected: True but was False, and this line is highlighted in red

Comment: Right, so that rules out the null exception I mentioned above.  I suggest at this point you put in some logging of some sort to see what `approvedBOm.Text` actually is within the test.  If it's not "Approved By xyz", it suggests your test is working...